# Column names returned by a stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to display the column names that can be returned by a stored procedure and allow users to select the column names they want and then execute the stored procedure and return data for the selected columns only. Is there a way to get just the columns names returned by a stored procedure without actually executing the stored proc/before execution

Comment: I think you'll have to modify the stored procedure, so that by passing a flag it could show only the column names without data.

Comment: You could do this with dynamic SQL I suppose. Let users pick from a list in front end, concatenate all column names and pass to the stored procedure and run the query with `sp_executesql`.

Comment: This kind of functionality would be much better handled by a VIEW. You can then build something on the client side which will dynamically construct the SELECT statement.

Comment: There are two ways I think. One is you can pass the selected column names to the stored procedure and using dynamic query return the result. Other option is during showing the result you just display only the selected columns, instead of all coulmns from stored procedure. It depends on how you are displaying it

Comment: where is this stored proc called from?

Comment: its called from a windows service

Answer (score 0):

Use DeriveParameters method to get the parameters from store procedure

```
public void GetParameter()
{

    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("sqlconnectionstring");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storeprocedurename", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();    
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
       // get the parameter name by p.ParameterName
    }
}
```